# Setting properties of a textbox?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to learn Microsoft's ASP.net mvc framework, and one of things I don't know how to do is change the properties of a form item (specifically a textbox).  Here's what I have so far:

`@Html.TextBox("activeQuery", "defaultValue", new {Width = 300, Height = 300 })`

That doesn't feel intuitively correct, but I just adapted the format from a post I found online.

I've been working with this framework for only an hour or two, so please excuse the very basic question.  Thanks for your response and patience in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve. if you are coming from asp.net web forms things are bit different in MVC. I would suggest you to go to the official site http://www.asp.net/mvc. It has good resources and videos to start with

Comment: I've never touched any semblance of ASP.net before.  I'm checking through some tutorials now; thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter is an anonymous object that defines the textbox's attributes. So you can just add your attribute names and values as property names and values of the anonymous object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493049.aspx

Comment: Looks like the example at the bottom was exactly what I needed; thanks.